# Core Data, loop VS search

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I am using core data in an application and basically wanted to know if anybody had an idea of which of these 2 processes would be faster...

I have a table View that requires matching an entry in core data with rows at the moment I put all core data classes in an array using:

```
NSArray *classArray = (NSArray *)[currentUser myCDClasses];

for(myCDClasses *class in classArray)
{
  if([class class_id] == theIDINeedToMatch)
  {
    myCDClasses *classForThisRow = class;
    break;
  }
}
```

What I would like to know is, if it would be faster to just predicate search according to the ID i need to retrieve ?

I think usually the max items it would have to for loop through would be about 40.

Comment: Fast Enumeration is always a nice idea , it is faster than even block enumerators(well in case of dictionary block would be a bit faster depending on the array size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you will notice any difference for 40 items. For a large dataset, using a predicate is probably faster, because the search is done on the SQLite level, and only the result is loaded into memory, whereas the "loop solution" requires that all objects that you compare against are "faulted-in" and read from the store file.